# Does it matter if I'm root or not when installing apache?

Tags: rhel, root, mysql, php, apache-httpd

I need to install a LAMP stack on a RHEL 6.7 server. Do I have to be root to install this or not?

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling from source, or using rpm / yum? Either way, you'd either have to be in the wheelgroup, sudo, or su ROOT to install / build most packages and dependencies you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your webserver listening on port 80 (where webservers usually listen, but if it's only for your own use, you could probably do with another port), it will need to be started by root, in that case you'll need root access at some point anyway.

RHEL 6.7 probably has packages with apache, mysql and php that just work, you'll probably need to be root to install those. (I've never used RHEL, so I'm not complete sure of anything related to it, but it would surprise me if things were different.)

You probably could get through installing apache in your home directory (or somewhere else you can write to without root access), and even make it usable, but there'll probably be a lot of work in it.

Answer (score 0):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html

You should be a power user of some degree- wheel, sudo, or su. 
I would advise against building in your home directory- apache will need some dependencies. It is best to install in it's default directory:

```
 /usr/local/apache2.
```

I have built from apache.org's directions reliably on standard installs- it should suffice.